# How to restrict NGINX rewrite 'location' with auth_basic_user_file

Tags: authentication, nginx, .htpasswd

I have the following location block in my NGINX server block:

```
location ~ ^/admin {
  auth_basic "Restricted";
  auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
  if (!-e $request_filename){
      rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?uri=$1;
  }
}
```

But it doesn't work.  The /etc/nginx/.htpasswd file exists and was generated using the htpasswd command:

```
sudo htpasswd -c /etc/nginx/.htpasswd admin
```

I've done this before but it just stopped working this time. The only difference this time is that I'm trying to do auth_basic_user_file inside of a rewrite block this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That config will not work because the rewrite phase, `if XYZ`, will always run before the access phase, `auth_XYZ`, regardless of how you arrange them in the location block.

[See Nginx Phase Order](http://nginx.org/en/docs/dev/development_guide.html#http_phases)

You need to add the authentication requirement to your php block in addition to the one you already have.